# Is adding k edges to spanning tree will result a graph with k cycle bases?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, graph-theory, trees

The number of cycle bases of a connected graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges is $m - n + 1$. Let's say, $v_k$ is the number of cycle bases of a graph resulting from adding $k$ edges to spanning tree. Thus:
$$v_k = (n-1+k)-n+1 =k $$
This result sort of confirming it. But this is not the proof. I was looking if there is a proof about this (preferably with a source I can look up)

Comment: Do you really mean "number of cycle bases" or do you mean "size of a basis of the cycle space"?

Comment: @MishaLavrov size of basis of the cycle space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is true. One possible cycle basis is to pick a spanning tree, and for each non-tree edge, take the cycle consisting of that edge plus the path inside the tree from one of its endpoints to the other. (So if there are $k$ more edges in the graph than in the spanning tree, there are $k$ basis elements.)

This is called the [fundamental cycle basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_basis#Fundamental_cycles).